# Python 3's input() returns a str that is not same object as the same str literal

Tags: python, string

I've come across an interesting behavior with Python 3 that I don't understand. I've understood that with the built-in immutable types like str, int, etc, that not only are two variables of the same value (both contain 'x') equal, they are literally the same object, which allows the use of the `is` operator. However, when I use the input() function, it seems to create a string object that is NOT the same object, but does have the same value.

Here's my python interactive prompt of this:

```
$ python
Python 3.2 (r32:88452, Feb 20 2011, 11:12:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = input()
test
>>> y = 'test'
>>> x is y
False
>>> x == y
True
>>> id(x)
4301225744
>>> id(y)
4301225576
```

Why is this?

Comment: This is just an informed guess, but I think that the string literals are interned, but the return value of input() is not. You could probably do the same thing with x = "".join('test') as it would create a new string object instead of returning the interned one

Comment: This isn't specific to 3.x, BTW.

Comment: @Bwmat this should be an answer and is the only answer I would accept, since all the ones below are parroting something the OP already knows (that `is` is not the same as `==` in general).

Comment: No, its not, but the input() function is. My question regarded the input() function from 3, which was raw_input before 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've understood that with the built-in immutable types like str, int, etc, that not only are two variables of the same value (both contain 'x') equal, they are literally the same object, which allows the use of the is operator.

This is your misconception: concerning the `int`s and `long`s, that is valid only for a few values; with strings of any kind, it may be true concerning the strings of one module, but not otherwise.

But [there is a builtin function `intern()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#intern) which interns any given string.

Comment: Thank You. There were a couple of good answers that almost answered me, but this one was spot on. You saw my misconception about the built-in immutable types, and answered it directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a properly behavior.

```
x == y #True because they have a the same value

x is y #False because x isn't reference to y
id(x) == id(y) #False because as the above
```

But:

```
x = input()
y = x  #rewrite reference of x to another variable
y == x and x is y and id(x) == id(y) #True
```

Comment: I understand why the equal operator works and the is operator does not. What I don't understand is why with this immutable type (``str``), it creates a new object instead of the typical python behavior of having them be the same literal object.

Comment: Perhaps I simply misunderstood what happens. Is it that the literals always are the same object, but there can be different objects with the same values if they are created a different way?

Comment: Because in order to 'have them be the same literal object", Python would have to somehow track down the first object in order to reuse it. It **may** be possible to process literals like that because they are created when the script is compiled, but it **still** isn't guaranteed; try setting up identical literals in two different modules, for example.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of an implementation detail - you can't rely on `is` returning `True` in general. Try this script:

```
x = 'test'
y = 'test'
print('%r: \'x == y\' is %s, \'x is y\' is %s' % (x, x == y, x is y))
x = 'testtest'
y = 'testtest'
print('%r: \'x == y\' is %s, \'x is y\' is %s' % (x, x == y, x is y))
for i in range(1, 100):
    x = 'test' * i
    y = 'test' * i
    print('%d: %r: \'x == y\' is %s, \'x is y\' is %s' % (i, x, x == y, x is y))
    if x is not y:
        break
```

This prints

```
'test': 'x == y' is True, 'x is y' is True
'testtest': 'x == y' is True, 'x is y' is True
1: 'test': 'x == y' is True, 'x is y' is True
2: 'testtest': 'x == y' is True, 'x is y' is False
```

On Jython, `is` returns `False` even in the first print.

Answer (score 0):

Values that are the same are **not** guaranteed to be the same instance. That's merely an optimization that you can't rely on. There aren't very many times that using `is` is appropriate, use `==` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I've understood that with the built-in immutable types like str, int, etc, that not only are two variables of the same value (both contain 'x') equal, they are literally the same object

No, that is not guaranteed, in the same way that if I speak of an orange that is physically indistinguishable from the one you are holding, it is not guaranteed that I don't have some other orange in mind that simply happens to look identical.